# Jumping Caterpillars program - stuck with it (JAVA ) geeksforgeeks.com

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, data-structures

**I'm stuck solving this Jumping Caterpillars practice program here**
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/jumping-caterpillars/0

My solution passes some testcases but fails one (maybe more) and I'm not able to spot why.
Please help me.

**The program question is:**
Given N leaves numbered from 1 to N . A caterpillar at leaf 1, jumps from leaf to leaf in multiples of Aj (Aj, 2Aj, 3Aj).
j is specific to the caterpillar. Whenever a caterpillar reaches a leaf, it eats it a little bit.. You have to find out how many leaves, from 1 to N, are left uneaten after all K caterpillars have reached the end. Each caterpillar has its own jump factor denoted by Aj, and each caterpillar starts at leaf number 1.

**Input:**
The first line consists of a integer T denoting the number of testcases. T test cases follow. Each test case consists of two lines of input. The first line consists of two integers: N, which denotes the number of leaves; and K, which denotes the number of caterpillars. Second line of each test case consists of K space seperated integers denoting the jumping factor of caterpillars.

**Output:**
For each testcase, in a new line, print a  single integer denoting the number of uneaten leaves.

**Example:
Input:**

1

10 3

2 3 5

**Output:**

2

**My Solution in JAVA**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nTestcases = s.nextInt();
        int nLeaves = s.nextInt();
        int nCaterpillars = s.nextInt();
        int[] catpillars = new int[nCaterpillars];
        IntStream.range(0,nCaterpillars).forEach(
            i -> catpillars[i] = s.nextInt());
        
        System.out.println(unVisited(nLeaves, catpillars));
        
    }
    
    static int unVisited(int nLeaves, int[] caterpillars){
        if(nLeaves <= 0) 
            return 0;
        if(caterpillars.length == 0 || caterpillars == null) 
            return nLeaves;
        List<Integer> leaves = new ArrayList<>();
        leaves = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,nLeaves)
            .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        for(int caterpillar : caterpillars){
            leaves = visitLeaves(caterpillar, leaves);
        }
        return leaves.size();
    }
    
    static List<Integer> visitLeaves(int caterpillar, List<Integer> leaves){
        for(int i=0; i< leaves.size(); i++){
            if(leaves.get(i) % caterpillar == 0){
                leaves.remove(i);        
            }
        }
        return leaves;
    }
}
```

Comment: changing the `List` while looping over it can be a problem (if not correcting the index). Example if caterpillars are given in descending order ( `3`, `2`). After first pass you get `1 2 4 5 ...` if now `2` is to be jumped, when `i = 1` code will remove `2` and list is `1 4 5`; now `i` is incremented to `2`, the next position. But now position `[1]`, that is value `4` in the list, is not tested

Comment: Suggestions: loop backwards, from end of list; or, when a value is removed, decrement `i` so on next iteration (after being incremented) the same position is tested again; or change data model, use a `boolean[]` to mark visited leafs, and loop by step to mark it...above code will also fail if one caterpillar jumps by `1`(or less?)

Comment: also no need to return/re-assign the list, only its content is being changed, not the list (instance)

Comment: @user15244370 You should provide a detailed explanation in the `Your Answer` panel.

Comment: @user15244370 It is not about reputation that much. *If you have a really good answer to the question, you should provide it to the one asking the question in a clear and expressive way. You do have a really good answer here.* You should do it. Obviously someone will do it if you do not.